# How one click on submit button will do UPDATE MySQL and reload the table contents in php immediately?

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I'm beginner for PHP and stuck for updating table contents from MySQL and loading the newly updated MySQL table contents at the same time with only one click on submit button.
In the table, there's input form which I can make change number of items and also submit button on each row.

I found similar answer on stack overflow ([php update mysql table via form, reload information on page immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116328/php-update-mysql-table-via-form-reload-information-on-page-immediately)).
and the answer uses concept like the below. 
I understood that I need to put DELETE and UPDATE before SELECT and RENDER.
also I understood `<input type="hidden" value="/*unique number*/" >` is needed to accomplish this task.
I can update the edited value using UPDATE and refreshing the page again and can see the price value has changed. But what I don't yet get is how I do two tasks with only one click.

```
    <?php
    // DELETE (your delete stuff)
    // UPDATE (your update stuff)

    // RETRIEVE (your SELECT query)
    ?>
    <table> <!-- your table markup -->
    <?php
    // RENDER (your while loop and such)
```

There're submit button for price change each row so `<input type="hidden" value"unique number">` is the key to do it.
I also tried to use `isset($_POST[""])` but probably was not using it in right way.

I'll write more details if needed. anybody know how to deal with this problem?

...and below is abstract idea of my code.

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>quantity</th>
        <th>status</th>
      </tr>
    <?php while (){ ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php /* render name */ ?></td>
        <td><?php /* render price */
                <input type="text" value=" /* value from MySQL table but changeable with submit button */ >
                print <input type="hidden" value="/* give unique value */" >
                <input type="submit" name="" value="SUBMIT">
        ?></td>
        <td><?php /* render quantity */ ?></td>
        <td><?php /* render status */ ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: You will have to use JavaScript for this. PHP is a preprocessor, meaning it can't do anything once the page is served to the browser (unless there's some JavaScript helping it out). The submit button should automatically refresh the page unless you use JavaScript to tell it not to. I would recommend using an [`XmlHttpRequest`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp) to send data to a back-end page and update the page content without having to reload it at all.

Comment: Thank you, Jesse. I'll look into the way using JavaScript.